# How to use DbConfiguration class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: database, configuration, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

Is there any way I can use DbConfiguration in .net core? 
For ex:

```
public class DbConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public DbConfig()
    {
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient",
        System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

I assume I need to get a .net framework dll and reference it in my project in order to use that class? My purpose of doing it is to put a annotation on DbContext class like below:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(DbConfig))]
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
```

and ultimately implement [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx) in .net core way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing your ASP.NET core using full .Net Framework (.Net 4.6) then all you need to do is add the dependency as below to your project.json file

```
"frameworks": {
    "net46": {}
 }
```

The DbConfiguration class from EntityFramework will be available to you.

But, If you are developing your ASP.NET Core using .NET Core, you need to use EntityFramework Core [Configuring DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)

Comment: Could you be more specific? How to configure `HistoryContext` for EFCore?